# Python smach userdata key not available

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new to smach and I have some question about userdata in smach. This is my code:

```
def main():
rospy.init_node('smach_example_state_machine')

sm_top = smach.StateMachine(outcomes=['outcome4','outcome5'],
                          input_keys=['sm_input'],
                          output_keys=['sm_output'])
sm_top.userdata.sm_input=1
with sm_top:
 smach.StateMachine.add('FOO', Foo(),
                        transitions={'outcome1':'BAR',
                                     'outcome2':'outcome4'},
                        remapping={'foo_counter_in':'sm_input',
                                   'foo_counter_out':'sm_data'})
 print 'the number is:  '
 print sm_top.userdata.sm_input
 print 'the number is:  '
 print sm_top.userdata.sm_data

 time.sleep(5)
 smach.StateMachine.add('BAR', Bar(),
                        transitions={'outcome1':'FOO'},
                        remapping={'bar_counter_in':'sm_data',
                                   'bar_counter_out':'sm_output'})

# Execute SMACH plan
outcome = sm_top.execute()
```

When I tried to print sm_top.userdata.sm_data the program crashed and told me sm_data key is not available. However I can access this key in the state Boo. I understand this might have something to do with pointer.(I would like to know the detail too).
My question is: Is there anyway to access sm_top.userdata.sm_data in the main function?
Also, is there a way to remap the output of a state to the input of two other states(1 to N)?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245380/python-smach-userdata-key-not-available/) by [orsonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28198/orsonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-11**:\

> However I can access this key in the state Boo

Might not have had enough coffee, but I don't see a *state Boo*? Did you mean to write *Foo*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Userdata should only be accessed within states/containers which declare read (input key) or write (output key) access, although it is usually fine to initialize internal userdata keys on container construction.

Anyways, your example fails for the following reason: The key `sm_data` is only written by state `Foo`. Consequently, it only exists after the state returns with one of its outcomes (assuming the state declared `foo_counter_out` as output key). This won't happen before calling `sm_top.execute()`, which is after the print statement in your example. Before the very last line, you only construct the state machine, but do not execute it.

Yes, a userdata key can be passed to any amount of states. Consider it just as a variable to be updated during state machine execution.

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2016-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0